# ggplot2 remove legend removes annotations

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am creating a plot with a 2nd y axis to note categories of fitness. I've gotten the categories and labels using hline and annotate. I have specified a fill to the box plot which produces a legend. This legend than covers the annotations, but removing the legend also removes all annotation. Is there a way to remove only the annotation. See code below:

Without legend:

```
fmsft <- ggplot(Fboxm, aes(test, count))

fmsft + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = test), show.legend = FALSE) + 
  labs(x="Test", y=expression("Estimated VO"["2Max"])) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 23.9, size = 1.3) + 
  annotate("text", label = "Very Poor",
           x = 7, y = 23.9) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,6), clip = "off") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 28.6, size = 1.3) + 
  annotate("text", label = "Poor",
           x = 7, y = 28.6) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 34.6, size = 1.3) + 
  annotate("text", label = "Fair",
           x = 7, y = 34.6) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 40.6, size = 1.3) + 
  annotate("text", label = "Good",
           x = 7, y = 40.6) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 46.5, size = 1.3) + 
  annotate("text", label = "Excellent",
           x = 7, y = 46.5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 56, size = 1.3) +
  annotate("text", label = "Superior",
         x = 7, y = 56)
```

[image: Nolegend]

With legend:

```
fmsft <- ggplot(Fboxm, aes(test, count))

fmsft + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = test)) + 
  labs(x="Test", y=expression("Estimated VO"["2Max"])) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 23.9, size = 1.3) + 
  annotate("text", label = "Very Poor",
           x = 7, y = 23.9) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,6), clip = "off") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 28.6, size = 1.3) + 
  annotate("text", label = "Poor",
           x = 7, y = 28.6) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 34.6, size = 1.3) + 
  annotate("text", label = "Fair",
           x = 7, y = 34.6) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 40.6, size = 1.3) + 
  annotate("text", label = "Good",
           x = 7, y = 40.6) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 46.5, size = 1.3) + 
  annotate("text", label = "Excellent",
           x = 7, y = 46.5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 56, size = 1.3) +
  annotate("text", label = "Superior",
         x = 7, y = 56)
```

[image: legend]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't have your data, so I didn't check to make sure this would work. However, I think that the reason the annotations have dropped off is because the space you used is no longer there. What you need to do is add `scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(mult = (0, 1)))` That `1` is going to create space on the right side of the graph so your words are visible. You may have to adjust this value until it fits, based on your data.

Comment: @Kat Thank you for answer. This did work in away, but expanded the plot area, so the text does appear but now had the grid theme as a background, and the geom_hline running over it

Comment: That is a problem! It looks like @r2evans has a good answer, then!

Comment: @Kat yea answer worked perfectly. Thanks for your help as well, I appreciate people trying to solve the issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `theme(plot.margin = unit(..., "cm"))` to adjust the right margin.

Demonstration using `mtcars`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 480), clip = "off") +
  annotate("text", label = "quuxbar", x = 540, y = 20)
gg
```

[image]

```r
gg + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.2, 2, 0.2, 0.2), "cm"))
```

[image]

FYI, the defaults:

```r
theme_get()$plot.margin
# [1] 5.5points 5.5points 5.5points 5.5points
```